# Does parse.coms javascript library iterate an NSArray

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform

```
var query =new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.containsAll("username", request.params.myArray);
```

I have the above query. myArray is a list of usernames that I want. But this is not working and Im getting an error back even though I know the fields exist. So, here are some questions?

I am sending an NSArray as my request pram. In the code below, that would be selectedNumbers which is an NSAarray.

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"StartSession"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"myArray":selectedNumbers

                                        }block:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {


                                    if (!error) {
                                        NSLog(@"%@", results);


                                    }else{
                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                    }
                                }];
```

Will parse know how to parse that?

If so, the problem must be my query. selectedNumbers will contain a list of user names that I have in the default User class and the supplied numbers should be found in their username column.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a permissions issue...  Try executing the query with the master key.

```
query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results) {

}, function(err) {

});
```

This assumes the query is in Cloud Code (which has access to the master key.)